# Pandas Drop Behavior

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just tried answering another question here on SO and ran into an issue of filtering a dataframe using `pd.drop`. Here is the example I gave:

```
import pandas as pd
import langdetect
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sentence':['es muy bueno','run, Forest! Run!','Ήξερα ότι θα εξετάζατε τον Μεταφραστή Google', 'This is Certainly en']})
df['Language'] = df['Sentence'].apply(lambda x: langdetect.detect(x))
# output
                                       Sentence Language
0                                  es muy bueno       es
1                             run, Forest! Run!       ro
2  Ήξερα ότι θα εξετάζατε τον Μεταφραστή Google       el
3                          This is Certainly en       en
```

Now I wanted to drop all rows where language is not `en`. When using `df.drop(df['Language'] != 'en')` it unexpectedly returns:

```
                                       Sentence Language
2  Ήξερα ότι θα εξετάζατε τον Μεταφραστή Google       el
3                          This is Certainly en       en
```

However, when I take the Boolean indexing it returns:

```
df['Language'] != 'en'
# output 

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: Language, dtype: bool
```

Now, I can get around this by using `df.loc[df['Language'] == 'en']`. But I am wondering why `drop` is behaving this way or if I've done something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) require `index` or `column` label

```
df.drop(df.index[(df['Language'] != 'en')])
Out[303]: 
            Sentence Language
3  ThisisCertainlyen       en
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) takes index or column label

```
labels : single label or list-like

Index or column labels to drop.
```

When you pass the following to df.drop on default axis (which is 0), its dropping rows 0 and 1 - corresponding to False(0) and True(1)

```
df['Language'] != 'en'

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
```

Though it can be done using df.drop as in @Wen's answer, the most idiomatic way would be to go for boolean indexing or df.query